# url with multiple optional arguments

Tags: django

right now I have a view to show info about some tickets and I'm trying to add a functionality to filter those tickets.

Say I will have 4 filters:

- Date
- Owner
- Category
- Status

Category  Status

I want to give the option to use some of those filters, all or none, the thing is I'm kinda lost in how can I make it work in the urls. So far I found that you can add some optional arguments but they appear in some sort of succession like:

/May/Jack/Gas/Accepted

But if I only select 2 filters like /Jack/Accepted/ it grabs the filters incorrectly.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Or some other method I can use instead of this. Ty

Comment: what have you tried so far. Post your urls.py and views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try and do this with URL arguments. Instead, use querystring arguments. The URL should be in the form:

```
my_path/?date=May&owner=Jack&category=Gas&status=accepted
```

and the URL pattern is just:

```
url(r'^my_path/$', views.my_view, 'my_url'),
```

and in the view you can access `request.GET['date']` etc.